# Openlayers and Jquery compatibility?

Tags: jquery, openlayers

JQuery - jquery-2.1.3.js
Openlayers - OpenLayers-2.13.1

I'm trying to print the map using Jquery [PrintThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis), unfortunately it returns an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name="OpenLayers_Control_LayerSwitcher_27_baseLayers"][value=Bing Aerial]
```

I tried removing the controls and it works but I don't want that to happen. So, which part/JS should I modify? probably the Openlayers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating the layer switcher control or removing it temporary from the map.
It sounds like a bug in the PrintThis plugin so try to put an issue in the github site.